# Instalación fallida de phpMyAdmin en Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

En un sistema de Ubuntu 16.04, tras tener instalado:
- Apache 2
- MySQL 8.0.11 (decir que esta versión incluye un "complemento de validación de contraseña" que no llegué a habilitar)
- PHP 7.0
he querido instalar, también, phpMyAdmin. Pero en la instalación me salido una serie de Warnings y/o Errores que, creo que hacen que a la hora de iniciar sesión en el navegador, no logre acceder al servidor de MySQL.

Decir que, hasta ahora, no había instalado antes phpMyAdmin en un Linux. Si, muchas veces, en un Windows.

Decir, también, que la instalación de tanto Apache, MySQL y PHP por la terminal fue satisfactoria.

Al querer instalar phpMyAdmin, por la terminal, igualmente, se produjeron ciertos problemas.

=> Comencé por esto:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
```

=> Entonces, salen una serie de preguntas para efectuar la configuración:

> - Servidor: **apache2**
> - Configure database for phpmyadmin with dbconfig-common?: **Si**
> - Contraseña para phpMyAdmin y confirmación de ésta: puse la misma contraseña que la que le puse al ROOT de MysQL.
> - Indicar la contraseña de ROOT de MySQL: la tecleo

Tras especificar estos pasos y darle a [Aceptar], me salto un primer ERROR:

> mysql: [ERROR] mysql: Empty value for 'port' specified . Your options
>   are:
>
> - abort - Causes the operation to fail; you will need to downgrade,
>     reinstall, reconfigure this package, or otherwise manually intervene
>     to continue using it. This will usually also impact your ability to
>     install other packages until the installation failure is resolved.
> - retry - Prompts once more with all the configuration questions
>     (including ones you may have missed due to the debconf priority
>     setting) and makes another attempt at performing the operation.
> - retry (skip questions) - Immediately attempts the operation again,
>     skipping all questions. This is normally useful only if you have
>     solved the underlying problem since the time the error occurred.

Logro corregir este ERROR antes de pulsar en [reintentar] con esto:

```
# Editar este archivo:
sudo nano /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf

# Cambiar el valor de este parámetro de vacío a 0:
dbc_dbport='0'
```

Paso, con esto, el ERRO anterior y paso a esta otra pantalla de configuración:

> - Connection method for MySQL database of phpmyadmin:
>
>   Unix socket
>
>   TCP/IP

El texto explicativo recomienda la opción de Unix que viene seleccionada por defecto, así que la dejo elegida y pulso [Aceptar].

Otras configuraciones salen:

> > Nombre de la base de datos para phpMyAdmin:
> >                 phpmyadmin

```
    >> Nombre de usuario en MySQL para la base de datos "phpMyAdmin":
        -> phpmyadmin

    >> Nombre de usuario administrador de la base de datos:
        -> root

    >> Contraseña del usuario administrador de la base de datos:
        -> de nuevo, pongo la misma contraseña que la de ROOT de MySsQL

    >> ¿Qué desea hacer con el archivo de configuración modificado "phpmyadmin.conf"? 
        -> conservar la versión local actualmente instalada
```

Tras [Aceptar] estos últimos pasos, me salta este otro ERROR

> An error occurred while installing the database:
>    │
>    │ mysql said: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL
>    │ syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>    │ for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'la_contraseña_dada'' at line 1 .
>    │ Your options are:
>    │  * abort - Causes the operation to fail; you will need to downgrade,
>    │    reinstall, reconfigure this package, or otherwise manually intervene
>    │    to continue using it. This will usually also impact your ability to
>    │    install other packages until the installation failure is resolved.
>    │  * retry - Prompts once more with all the configuration questions
>    │    (including ones you may have missed due to the debconf priority
>    │    setting) and makes another attempt at performing the operation.
>    │  * retry (skip questions) - Immediately attempts the operation again,

Elegí la opción de "***abort***" pues no sabía cómo resolverlo.
Tras esto, termina el proceso de instalación de phpMyAdmin sin indicar si la instalación se completó o no aparte de este último ERROR.

Por último, habilito ciertas librerías de PHP que se especificaron en el comando de instalación de phpMyAdmin:

```
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```

Y reinicio el Apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Entonces,

- accedo a la pantalla de inicio de sesión de phpMyAdmin con

  http://localhost/phpmyadmin
- inserto los datos de acceso

  usuario: root
  password: el_especificado_para_root

Pero, en vez de acceder a la pantalla de inicio de phpMyAdmin, me salen estos mensajes de ERROR en la propia pantalla de inicio de sesión:

> ## 2054 - The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
>
> La conexión para controluser, como está definida en su configuración, fracasó.

Debido a ello, no puede acceder, por tanto, por phpMyAdmin al servidor MySQL.

Como he dicho antes, hasta ahora, he hecho muchas instalaciones de phpMyAdmin no en Linux pero si en Windows.
En Windows, solo hace falta descargar el comprimido de phpMyAdmin, descomprimirlo en el directorio raíz de Apache para sitios web y, luego, editar su archivo de configuración "config.inc.php" en el que especificar el método de inicio de sesión en MySQL entre otras cosas.

Como curiosidad, he localizado el mencionado archivo en Ubuntu en esta dirección
    /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
y decir que está vacío totalmente. ¿Por qué? ¿Acaso no es esté el archivo o está en otra ubicación el verdadero archivo de configuración de phpMyAdmin?

Por tanto, ¿alguien sabría decirme como solucionar todo esto y poder, finalmente, iniciar correctamente la sesión en phpMyAdmin?
¿Acaso el ERROR sería el haber dado para phpMyAdmin la misma contraseña que para el ROOT de MySQL?

Gracias por toda sugerencia o idea que pueda ser útil para encontrar una solución al problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pues me toca responderme a mí mismo. Voy a poner los pasos que he seguido para llegar a la solución, por si a otra persona le sirve.

En muchas de las respuestas a temas parecidos que he llegado a ver en las búsquedas, se recomienda bajar de versión de la 8 a la 5.7 de MySQL, para evitar los problemas de autenticación que, parece, phpMyAdmin no termina de soportar.
Yo he llegado a encontrar otro camino para seguir con el MySQL 8 instalado.

Me he inspirado en las respuestas de este otro post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948350/phpmyadmin-on-mysql-8-0
Sobre todo, en la penúltima respuesta.

Pues eso, ahí voy:

- Abrir el siquiente archivo para editarlo
  sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
- A no ser que haya sido editado antes, salvo dos líneas con unas instrucciones que empiezan por "!includedir", este archivo no contiene más que comentarios.
- Antes de las mencionadas dos líneas, incluir estas dos nuevas líneas:

  [mysqld]
  default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password
- Guardar el archivo.
- Ahora, entrar en MySQL con el usuario ROOT tecleando su contraseña actual.

  sudo mysql -u root -p
- Crear un nuevo usuario, por ejemplo, con el nombre de ROOTX y una contraseña:

  create user 'rootx'@'localhost' identified by 'rootx-pass';
- Darle todos los privilegios sobre todo

  grant all privileges on * . * to 'rootx'@'localhost';
- Y, para terminar,

  flush privileges;
- Ahora, intentar volver acceder al phpMyAdmin con los datos del nuevo usuario creado ROOTX.
- Una vez se ha accedido a la página de inicio de phpMyAdmin, entrar en la tabla "user" de la base de datos "mysql".
- Pulsar sobre el nombre del usuario "root" para abrir su tabla de privilegios.
  En la parte de arriba de esta tabla, existe un botón para efectuar un
  [Cambio de contraseña]. Pulsarlo.
- Elegir la opción de "Sin contraseña" y [Guardar].
- Volver a la tabla antes mencionada de "user" y volver a dar en el nombre de usuario "root" para volver a la misma tabla de privilegios y poder volver a la sección de [Cambio de contraseña] otra vez.
- Ahora, habilitar la opción de "Contraseña" y establecer una y confirmarla en la segunda casilla.
  En el menú desplegable de "Hashing de la contraseña", dejar seleccionada la opción de "Native MySQL authentication". Y [Guardar].
- En principio, tras cerrar la sesión de phpMyAdmin, el querer iniciar sesión con los nuevos datos de ROOT será satisfactorio esta vez.

Saludos para todos a los que les interese. Espero que esto sirva de ayuda a todo al que se le presente un problema entre el MySQL 8 y el phpMyAdmin.

NOTA: por cierto, cuando se da la pregunta por resuelta, ¿cuál es la forma oficial de dejar el tema cerrado o solucionado?

Comment: Puedes marcar tu respuesta como aceptada después de 48 horas. Aquí puedes encontrar mas información [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)